# Write a program using an array that ask user to input 10 numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, std, average

Exercise text:

> Write a program using array that asks user to input 10 numbers, then calculates the average of those numbers and finds out the total number that is greater or equal to the average. For example, you have input 10 numbers as: 1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5. The average is 0. The total number that is greater or equal to the average is 5 which are 1,2,3,4,5.
>
> You have to use the loop to do this problem.

My code so far:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double nums[10];
    double sum = 10;
    double averageNums;
    int numsGreaterThan = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Enter number " << i +1 << ": ";
        cin >> nums;
        sum = sum + nums;
    }
    averageNums = sum / 10;

    for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
    {
        if ( nums[j] >= averageNums )
            numsGreaterThan++; 
    }
    cout << numsGreaterThan << " numbers are greater than the average.";

    system ("pause");
}
```

The errors I'm struggling with:

1. > Error  1   error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'double [10]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
2. > Error  2   error C2111: '+' : pointer addition requires integral operand
3. > IntelliSense: no operator ">>" matches these operands
   >           operand types are: std::istream >> double [10]
4. > IntelliSense: expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type

Comment: It would be better if you add line number in error messages.

Comment: You really should not put `using namespace std` in front of an include

Answer (score 2):

```
cin >> nums;
```

should be

```
cin >> nums[i];
```

So

```
sum = sum + nums;
```

should be

```
sum = sum + nums[i];
```

Because `nums` is an array and it should be indexed. You are trying to pass an array to `cin` and `+` operator with `double`. Hence, you are getting error.

Comment: wow that easy with just two letters thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You need to index the array:

```
cin >> nums[i];
sum = sum + nums[i];
```